# Partition disappears after modifying fstab

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

So, I'm trying to auto-mount a Windows partition at startup. This is the line that I added in the `fstab` file:

`UUID=4462435862434E3C  /boot   ntfs    defaults,user   0       2`

I read [this tutorial](http://www.linuxstall.com/fstab/) and couple of other posts on SO, so it seems like the configuration I wrote is correct but, upon loading my Ubuntu, the partition is gone. I cannot see it in the window manager.

I also tried having just `defaults` for the `<options>` section, without `user`, but still the same effect.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I went along with Pilot6's solution, but used `/media/my_username` instead of `/media/data` or `/media/user/my_username` since both of the last 2 suggestion were causing error at system boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not mount partitions to `/boot`. That is fundamentally wrong. It may get your system unworkable.

To see partitions in your file manager you need to mount them to sub-directories of `/media`

The line should look like

```
UUID=4462435862434E3C /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

You will also need to change the “locale=en_US.utf8” option to one suitable for your location and language if you are not in the USA. You can determine your locale with this terminal command

```
locale
```

You may also need to change ownership of the mount point to your user by running.

```
 sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/Data
```

or another mount point to give access to partition contents.

Comment: Ok, I see. Just one question - the partition is located in the directory `/media/my_username`, but not in `/media/data`. When I write it, should I change it to my case or it should stay as you described it - `/media/data`? If is should be `.../data` then can you please elaborate why?

Comment: When you click a partition it is automatically mount to `/media/user/some_name`. But you can choose another directory when you set it up in fstab. It does not make much difference.

Comment: Well, which would be the "most correct" way?

Comment: It's up to you to choose. Just do it with "user", if you need an advice.

Comment: I have mounted the partition by clicking on it and then I ran the command `df -T` and the partition is mounted at `/media/my_username`, so I think I will go along with that one.